# impressionist view count not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, impressionist

i have a rails app where i am using **impressionist gem** to count the vieew made on the show page of my post model.
But it's not updating the views,(the views shows 0)

in my gem file i added:

```
gem 'impressionist'
```

Then:

```
rails g impressionist
```

then:

```
rake db:migrate
```

i added this to my **post.rb** file:

```
   is_impressionable
```

**post controller**

```
impressionist actions: [:show], unique: [:session_hash]
```

in my **show view** file:

```
<%= "#{@post.impressionist_count} views so far!" %>
```

I think i have did everything right, but don't know why the view count is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling this on top of the controller for a single action you can try:

```
impressionist(@post, "optional message", :unique => [:session_hash])
```

Then try

```
@post.impressionist_count
```

Or you can also try

```
@post.impressions_count
```

Comment: Hey @Chetan sorry am new to this xan you please tell me where to add: impressionist(@product, "unique view", :unique => [:session_hash])